# What is most efficient for GCD?

Tags: algorithms, recursion, arithmetic

I know that Euclid’s algorithm is the best algorithm for getting the GCD (great common divisor) of a list of positive integers.
But in practice you can code this algorithm in various ways. (In my case, I decided to use Java, but C/C++ may be another option).

I need to use the most efficient code possible in my program.

In recursive mode, you can write:

```
static long gcd (long a, long b){
    a = Math.abs(a); b = Math.abs(b);
    return (b==0) ? a : gcd(b, a%b);
  }
```

And in iterative mode, it looks like this:

```
static long gcd (long a, long b) {
  long r, i;
  while(b!=0){
    r = a % b;
    a = b;
    b = r;
  }
  return a;
}
```

---

There is also the Binary algorithm for the GCD, which may be coded simply like this:

```
int gcd (int a, int b)
{
    while(b) b ^= a ^= b ^= a %= b;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: I think this is too subjective, and perhaps even better suited for StackOverflow. "Most efficient in practice" depends on many (even unpredictable) factors, such as the underlying architechture, memory hierarchy, size and form of the input etc.

Comment: uhmm you are right, but if you look recursive tree in fibonacci number generator, you have a problem of CS. So I'm finding if there are a similar problem.

Comment: This is the same algorithm expressed in recursive and iterative ways. I think their difference is negligible since Euclid algorithm converges pretty fast. Choose one that fits your preference.

Comment: You might want to try profiling these two.  Since the recursive version is a tail call, it is not unlikely that the compiler actually emits almost the same code.

Comment: this is wrong. should be while b != 0, and then return a. Otherwise it bugs out on division by zero. also don't use recursion if you have really big gcds....you get a pile of stack and function states...why not just go iterative?

Comment: Note that there are asymptotically faster GCD algorithms.  E.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm

Comment: @NealYoung: Sure it is asymptotically faster? The article says "60% faster" which is nice but not asymptotically faster.

Comment: @gnasher729, I think so... from the article: "For arbitrary-precision arithmetic, neither the Euclidean algorithm nor the binary GCD algorithm are fastest, as they both take time that is a quadratic function of the number of input digits. Instead, recursive methods that combine ideas from the binary GCD algorithm with the Schönhage–Strassen algorithm for fast integer multiplication can find GCDs in near-linear time.[11]"  Also I think there are others?

Comment: You say you need the most efficient code for your programme, but I wonder how hard you have thought about that. The need for optimisation does indeed keep arising, but the usual advice is to choose your algorithms well (which may rule out Euclid’s!) and implement straightforwardly but in such a way that you can speed up whatever parts turn out in practice to matter most.

Comment: I can't recognise a/the *Binary GCD algorithm* in the like titled code snippet - just a weird way to exchange the values of two variables.

Comment: As @greybeard says, this is *not* the Binary GCD !

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your two algorithms are equivalent (at least for positive integers, what happens with negative integers in the imperative version depends on Java's semantics for `%` which I don't know by heart). In the recursive version, let $a_i$ and $b_i$ be the argument of the $i$th recursive call:
$$\begin{gather*}
  a_{i+1} = b_i \\
  b_{i+1} = a_i \mathbin{\mathrm{mod}} b_i \\
\end{gather*}$$

In the imperative version, let $a'_i$ and $b'_i$ be the values of the variables `a` and `b` at the beginning of the $i$th iteration of the loop.
$$\begin{gather*}
  a'_{i+1} = b'_i \\
  b'_{i+1} = a'_i \mathbin{\mathrm{mod}} b'_i \\
\end{gather*}$$

Notice a resemblance? Your imperative version and your recursive version are calculating exactly the same values. Furthermore, they both end at the same time, when $a_i=0$ (resp. $a'_i=0$), so they perform the same number of iterations. So algorithmically speaking, there is no difference between the two. Any difference will be a matter of implementation, highly dependent on the compiler, the hardware it runs on, and quite possibly the operating system and what other programs are running concurrently.

The recursive version makes only [tail recursive calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion). Most compilers for imperative languages do not optimize these, and so it is likely that the code they generate will waste a little time and memory constructing a stack frame at each iteration. With a compiler that optimizes tail calls (compilers for functional languages almost always do), the generated machine code may well be the same for both (assuming you harmonize those calls to `abs`).

Answer (score 9):

For numbers that are small, the binary GCD algorithm is sufficient.

GMP, a well maintained and real-world tested library, will switch to a special half GCD algorithm after passing a special threshold, a generalization of Lehmer's Algorithm. Lehmer's uses matrix multiplication to improve upon the standard Euclidian algorithms. According to the docs, the asymptotic running time of both HGCD and GCD is `O(M(N)*log(N))`, where `M(N)` is the time for multiplying two N-limb numbers.

Full details on their algorithm can be found [here](https://gmplib.org/manual/Subquadratic-GCD.html#Subquadratic-GCD).

Comment: The link really does not provide full details, and doesn't even define what a "limb" is...

Comment: @einpoklum https://gmplib.org/manual/Nomenclature-and-Types.html#index-Limb

Answer (score 3):

As I know Java doesn’t support tail recursion optimization in general, but you can test your Java implementation for it; if it doesn’t support it, a simple `for`-loop should be faster, otherwise recursion should be just as fast. On the other hand, these are bit optimizations, choose the code you think is easier and more readable.

I should also note that the fastest GCD algorithm is not Euclid’s algorithm, [Lehmer’s algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer%27s_GCD_algorithm) is a bit faster.

Comment: Do you mean _as **far** as I know_? Do you mean the language specification does not mandate this optimisation (it would be surprising if it did), or that most implementations do not implement it?

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use recursivity to replace a tight loop.  It is slow.  Don't rely on the compiler to optimize it out.  Second, in your code, you call Math.abs() within every recursive calls, which is useless.

In your loop, you can easily avoid temporary variables and swapping a and b all the time.

```
int gcd(int a, int b){
    if( a<0 ) a = -a;
    if( b<0 ) b = -b;
    while( b!=0 ){
        a %= b;
        if( a==0 ) return b;
        b %= a;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Swapping using the a ^= b ^= a ^= b makes the source shorter but takes many instructions to execute.  It will be slower than the boring swap with a temporary variable.

Comment: “Avoid recursivity. It is slow” — presented as general advice, this is bogus. It depends on the compiler. Usually, even with compilers that don't optimize recursion, it isn't slow, just stack-consuming.

Comment: But for short code like this, the difference is significant.  Stack-consuming means writing to and reading from memory.  That is slow.  The code above runs on 2 registers.  Recursivity also means doing calls, which is longer than a conditional jump.  A recursive call is much harder for branch prediction and harder to inline.

Answer (score 0):

For **small numbers**, % is quite an expensive operation, perhaps
the simpler recursive

```
GCD[a,b] := Which[ 
   a==b , Return[a],
   b > a, Return[ GCD[a, b-a]],
   a > b, Return[ GCD[b, a-b]]
];
```

is quicker? (Sorry, Mathematica code and not C++)

Comment: It doesn't look right.  For b==1, it should return 1.  And GCD[2,1000000000] will be slow.

Comment: Ah, yes, I made a mistake. Fixed (I think), and clarified.

Comment: Normally, GCD[a,0] should also return a.  Yours loops forever.

Comment: I'm downvoting as your answer only contains code. We like to focus on ideas on this site. For instance, why is % an expensive operation? Speculation on a piece of code is not really a good answer for this site, in my opinion.

Comment: I think the idea that modulo is slower than subtraction can be considered folklore. It holds both for small integers (subtraction usually takes one cycle, modulo rarely does) and for large integers (subtraction is linear, I'm not sure what the best complexity is for modulo but it's definitely worse than that). Of course you also need to consider the number of necessary iterations.

Comment: This will be extremely slow. Given $n,1$ as input, it runs for exponentially many steps (in the input length, $\log n$).

Comment: Even though this post does not directly answer the question, it brings up some valid points. Firstly it presents a third, valid GCD variant, which was not considered by the author of the question. While it is true that integer division has become much faster on modern CPUs, subtraction still is magnitudes faster in my experience. The author also carefully qualified his answer with "perhaps" and "for small numbers". I disagree with the criticism against this answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: Practical performance questions are highly application-specific and can only be satisfyingly answered by application-specific benchmarks that sufficiently represent field conditions. This answer uses a synthetic benchmark instead, which may not at all be representative of Your specific application.*

A while ago, I ran a [little synthetic benchmark](https://github.com/DirkToewe/jaaa/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/jaaa/util/IMathBenchmark_gcd_int.java) (long version [here](https://github.com/DirkToewe/jaaa/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/jaaa/util/IMathBenchmark_gcd_long.java)) to answer, once and for all, which one of the following GCD algorithms is the fastest:

- a) Subtraction-based Euclid's Algorithm
- b) Division/Modulo-based Euclidean Algorithm
- c) Binary GCD

The answer was a clear and resounding: d) A combination of all of the above. So without further ado, I proudly present to You: The tribrid GCD algorithm!

```java
public static long tribridGCD( long x, long y )
{
  x = abs(x);
  y = abs(y);
  int l = Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(x); x >>>= l;
  int r = Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(y); y >>>= r;
  int shift = min(l,r);
  if( x > y ) {
    long z = x; x = y; y = z;
  }
  while( x != 0 ) {
    long z = x > (y>>>1) ? y-x : y%x;
    y = x;
    x = z;
    // Invariant: x <= y && (y is odd)
    x >>>= Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(x);
  }
  return y << shift;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you present as the Binary GCD algorithm is *not* the Binary GCD algorithm, because it still uses the modulo (remainder) operator $\%$ (in fact it is the standard algorithm with the swap-via-xor trick, which probably makes it slower). This is unfair in the comparison as modulo is a costly operation. The real Binary algorithm only uses shifts and subtractions, notoriously fast.

Anyway, telling the most efficient algorithm is not possible for several reasons:

- the answer can be machine-dependent,
- the answer can even be dependent on the input value, and
- the GCD is pretty fast to compute, and in practice it is impossible to measure short execution times accurately.

Answer (score -2):

**Euclid Algorithm is most efficient for calculating GCD:**

```
Static long gcd(long a,long b)
{
if(b==0)
return a;
else
return gcd(,a%b);
}
```

***example:-***

```
Let A = 16, B = 10.
GCD(16, 10) = GCD(10, 16 % 10) = GCD(10, 6)
GCD(10, 6) = GCD(6, 10 % 6) = GCD(6, 4)
GCD(6, 4) = GCD(4, 6 % 4) = GCD(4, 2)
GCD(4, 2) = GCD(2, 4 % 2) = GCD(2, 0)


Since B = 0 so GCD(2, 0) will return 2.
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The asker presents two versions of Euclid and asks which is faster. You don't seem to have noticed that and just declare the recursive version to be the only Euclid's algorithm, and assert with no evidence whatsoever that it's faster than everything else.